# Not sure how to assign a list of objects to a user in .net core

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, orm

I created a project with entity(I mean users). I want every user to have a List of Cars which belong to them. So in ApplicationUser I have this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public List<Car> Cars { get; set; } = new List<Car>();
    }
```

This is my AuthDbContext :

```
public class AuthDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public AuthDbContext(DbContextOptions<AuthDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

And finally here is my Car.cs:

```
public class Car
    {
        [Key]
        private Guid CarId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(255)")]
        private string Make { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(255)")]
        private string Model { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Owner")]
        private int OwnerId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        private ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }

        [Required]
        private DateTime Built { get; set; }

        private List<RepairService> RepairServices { get; set; }

        public Car()
        {
        }

        public Car(string make, string model, int ownerId, ApplicationUser owner, DateTime built, List<RepairService> repairServices)
        {
            CarId = Guid.NewGuid();
            Make = make;
            Model = model;
            OwnerId = ownerId;
            Owner = owner;
            Built = built;
            RepairServices = repairServices;
        }
```

Every time I try to run an Add-Migration I get this error:

The entity type 'Car' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'.

If I am correct I need every car to have an ID, so I am able to assign them to individual users.

Do I need another DbContext maybe? Or I can store those Cars in the AuthDbContext?

Comment: I think the issue might be, because you marked all properties as private in the Car model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial problem was I set every field as private, it should have been public

The problem is solved